# How to determine a "Hit\miss" system?

Tags: rpg, mathematics

I always try to fix my problems on my own, but i've reached a point where my mind is stuck so i trust myself in your hands, if you're willing to help and have the time.

I'm starting to make a RPG system, and I find myself struggling at the first formula: How can I determine if a character hits or miss?

Let me explain; the matter is not so simple, or i would have done it already, but what I don't understand are lots of things, and i'll show you:

Character's BaseHit is called "Precision", and it is calculated with this formula=

```
Pre.=MeleeHitAbility + MeleeWeaponHit x WeaponCharacterAbility
```

And as you can see it's pretty elementary, but now things start to get complex; now that i have my BaseHit value, how do i determine if my character misses, or maybe hits but the opponent dodge, or maybe block, or if my character gain a full hit, or even a critical?

Just so you know, my problem only rotates around these four chances, as I already have formulas for anything, but i really can't decide how to apply all of them in one simple hit.

I understand it could be easily done with if\then\else functions, but it doesn't convince me, it doesn't feel right; am I forced to make a formula for all of those possibilities? or there is a way I can integrate them all in one?

Also, if I am to make four formulas, how do I determine and tell the player the percentage for miss, hit, being blocked, being dodged or critical?

One last thing, I am aware that is probably not possible what I ask, so if it's not, do you know of a way to make it more convincing? because four formulas feels too much like four tries from just one hit, and it feels strange to me.

EDIT: Since I literally have no idea how to express myself with words, i've done this little block system. Also, what I'm requiring is just a formula sample that has three output values, basically i ask for an example of some sort, the rest is already made and decided, as you can see from the picture; I only need that one piece to make it work, and if you need more info about how I want to make it work, I want the formula to make a check roll against one of the enemy stat, then the other, and decide if the enemy is hit, dodge or block.

EDIT2: About how the player should see it, I basically want a simple display on the side of the screen so when the player click on the opponent it can tell the player the percentage success of "FullHit\Block\Dodge" so that he\she may decide what opponent to take and whatnot.

[image: BlockSystem]

Comment: It is easy to design *a* system like that, but question is which one would you like? Can you specify how would you like it to act/work? For example, do you *want to* apply all at once or one by one(it makes huge difference when designing other systems), e.g.: with 50% dodge and 50% block, if applied at once there is 0% to hit, but when applied one after another, there is 0.5 * 0.5 = 25% chance to hit. Do you want flat function mapping rating->% or with diminishing? ...and tens of similar questions, please try to include as many details as you can on how it should behave.

Comment: The system should display for the player the percentage for each possibility so the player can decide better

Every possibility of dodge or block has its opposite value from the opponent:

opponent dodge check = Flexibility

opponent block check = Technique

Criticals are also determined by another value from the attacker, "Reflexes", aside from other factors

I would like a flat function mapping, to keep it simple.

"one by one" is close to what i want, but i wish for the attacker to have a chance at all of them and the system to determine the successful one

Comment: I agree with what wondra says.  You're designing this all backwards.  First you must choose what you want it to play like and only then start coming up with the math to make it happen.  Pro tip: design all the math in an excel spreadsheet, if you can't make the formulas and understand the graphs they produce then you don't have a prayer of balancing the thing in code...

Comment: That may be the case, but that's the thing, i really need to know if "all at once" or "one by one" are my only options, of if i can try some more complex algebra to make it work together, because i have already everything planned except for this, i mean i know i can do it in many ways, and i know how to do it in those ways, but it doesn't feel right, so the core of my problem is:

-What are all my options for making it work?-

if you think it would help i can write all of the concept here, but i don't know if i'm allowed to make more than one comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, there are three possible outcomes of a successful hit:

- The enemy blocks and receives reduced damage
- The enemy dodges, receives no damage and an advantage on their next roll
- The enemy neither blocks nor dodges and receives full damage

This begs the question of what has priority: The dodging or the blocking mechanic?

One option is to first check one of those mechanics and only when it doesn't occur check the other. In that case the one which is checked first will happen more frequently. Regarding calculating the likeliness: The likeliness of the first mechanic happening is unmodified, the likeliness of the second is reduced by the fail-chance of the first. So when the first mechanic has a 60% chance of failing and the second a 40% chance of succeeding, the actual chance that the second event happens is 24% (60% of 40%)

Another option is to check both mechanics and then use the one where the random number generator generates a success by a greater margin.

Let's say the character has a 40% block chance and a 30% dodge chance on a particular attack. The random number roll(s) for the block test results in something which would have also succeeded at a 30% chance, the random result for the dodge test is slightly better and would also have worked with just 25%. In that case the block-test succeeded within a margin of 10% and the dodge-test within a margin of 5%. In that case the character would block, not dodge, because the block-test result was further below the result the character required.

When you use this option then not only are both mechanics on equal grounds, you can also add more damage mitigation mechanics later.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i meant and as for the "greater margin" solution is what i asked; to apply this, should i make two dinstict checks on both then make the system choose, or is there a formula i'm not aware of that allows me to do all of it in one line?

Comment: @HayedoBonda When there is such a formula I would advise you against using it, because it would likely lead to quite unreadable code.

Comment: thank you very much for your advice, would that apply even if I use numPy or Coq with third-party scripting?

Comment: @HayedoBonda I am not familiar with either numPy or Coq, but likely it would still apply. You will have a function with percent-values as input and `0`, `1` or `2` as output. That can only end up in a mess only a mathematician can decipher in under an hour.

Comment: Yes, i thought this could be a problem; what if I maintain the values as numbers, and translate them later in percentage with parallel functions? Will it avoid such chaos?